# Send object name into a function

Tags: contact, object, reflection

I was trying to pass an object name to a function as an String but I was 99% sure that it won't work and it didn't work. So I am wondering how is it possible to send an object name to function.

```
void createNewObject(String obj) // I tried Object obj as well
{
    obj newObj = new obj();   //which does not work
    newObj.name = 'test';
    ...
}
```

This is how I want to call:

```
String objName = 'Contact';
createNewObject(objName);
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Finally I had to do some controls in my function as follows, and it is resolved with less duplicating amount of code.

```
 void createNewObject(String obj) // I tried Object obj as well
{
    sObject s = new sObject();
    if (obj=='Contact')
    {
        Contact objectToAdd = new Contact();
        s = objectToAdd;
    }
    if (obj == 'Account')
    {
        Account objectToAdd = new Account();
        s = objectToAdd;
    }

    s.name = 'test';
    ...
}
```

Comment: pass it as a sobject means createNewObject(sObject obj)

Comment: @ShravanBoddula the problem is that it may be not sObject as well

Comment: When possible, you should consider using [SObject tokens](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) instead of a String. Using a String can introduce subtle errors when there are typos, and using a token binds the metadata type to the class, which can help you find code that uses the SObject (say, because you want to delete the object later).

Comment: @sfdcfox Actually I am reading files from server which each of them refers to different objects which should be inserted to Salesforce, so I am writing this function in order to avoid duplicating the code. Where in the function I will send also the apiNames of that object as well.

Comment: @reshad You should use Type.forName as ytid said, in that case. Using the code you specified is unnecessary and will likely cause maintenance nightmares in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to instantiate `SObject` records specifically, you can check the global describe.

```
public static void createObject(String objectType)
{
    SObjectType schemaType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectType);
    if (schemaType == null) return;
    SObject record = schemaType.newSObject();
    record.put('Name', 'Some Value');
    //insert?
}
```

Note that calling `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` consumes quite a bit of CPU Time. If you intend to call this function in a loop, you will need to modify your design with that in mind. If you intend to insert the resulting record, you will also want to return it from the function, so you can perform your DML Operation outside the loop as well.

Comment: Actually I used sObject objectToAdd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(obj).newSObject(); in order to resolve the problem

Comment: Hi @Andrian_Larson, is there are any major differences between using Type and SObjectType approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Hi man you can do something like this.

```
public Object createNewObject(String obj)
{
    Object obj = Type.forName(obj).newInstance();
    return obj;
}
```

```
String objName = 'Contact';
Contact cont = (Contact)createNewObject(objName);
```

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: @reshad You don't need to write if/else statements you can do something like this

Comment: SObject obj = Type.forName(obj).newInstance();
    obj.put('Name', 'test')

Comment: But I need also a list of these objects which I did not mention in the question

Comment: What do you mean List of objects?

Comment: If you want to group them then by type you can create Map
Map<String, SObject>, where String will correspond to your type

Comment: @reshad Typo - Map<String, List<SObject>>